# How to get flex 4.6 mobile application as SWF?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder, flex-mobile, flex4.6

I am running a flex mobile application. The goal is to create a SWF file from the same project without having to rewrite a new project.

I followed this tutotial
[mobile flex to swf](http://www.riagora.com/2011/08/flex-mobile-in-the-browser/)

But this gave me a blank result and source code is not provided.
Any clue ?

Regards